# What if I push twice to gerrit and the reviewer tries to merge the last one

Tags: git, gerrit

I've worked with Gerrit for a while and known the basic workflow of Gerrit.
[image]

Up to now, everything is OK: When I finish my coding job, I push my codes to Gerrit, then Jenkins and my leader start to work. If my leader(reviewer) +2 for my codes and Jenkins finishes its job without any error, my codes will be merged to the branch mater. This is quite clear and simple.

But, what if I push my changes twice in a very short period? Let's say I pushed A and then I pushed B. Both of them trigger Jenkins to do its jobs. At the same time, for some reason, my leader(reviewer) didn't review A but he reviewed B immediately. Then he +2 for B. Meaning that, A haven't been merged to the branch master but my leader is trying to merge B to the branch master. BUT, A is the parent of B. Obviously, logically, merging A must happen before merging B.

I want to know what Gerrit will do for this case. Will it generate an error to hint the reviewer to review the previous push?

Comment: I don't know about gerrit, but conceptually it depends on whether you force push or not. If you force push, B replaces A and A is no longer relevant. If you regular push and add more commits, then B is a superset of A, so if you merge in B, by definition you have already merged in A too.

Comment: Note my previous comment assumes A and B are on the same Git branch. If they aren't then the comment is not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `B` is dependent on `A` and `A` is not ready to be submitted, `B` is blocked. The submit button on `B` page is disabled.

If you want to submit `B` anyway, you need to rebase `B` first so that it gets independent from `A`. The rebase could fail due to conflicts.